# how to use ExternalStorageStats

Tags: android, storage, android-external-storage

Hi can anybody tell me how can I use **ExternalStorageStats** class. Basically I want to get storage usage by getting image bytes, audio bytes, video bytes, app bytes using this class. By the way, I successfully got total storage, free storage, used storage by using **StorageStatsManager** class but found nothing on the internet how to use **ExternalStorageStats** class to get image bytes, audio bytes, video bytes, app bytes. I even didn't find any helpful content from official documentation and the link to official documentation is given below.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/ExternalStorageStats

Code for getting total storage, free storage, used storage by using **StorageStatsManager** class is given below

```
final StorageStatsManager storageStatsManager = (StorageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
final StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
final List<StorageVolume> storageVolumes = storageManager.getStorageVolumes();
final UserHandle user = android.os.Process.myUserHandle();
for (StorageVolume storageVolume : storageVolumes) {
            final String uuidStr = storageVolume.getUuid();
            final UUID uuid = uuidStr == null ? StorageManager.UUID_DEFAULT : UUID.fromString(uuidStr);

            try {
                    Log.d("AppLog", "storage:" + uuid + " : " + storageVolume.getDescription(context) + " : " + storageVolume.getState());
                    Log.d("AppLog", "getTotalBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStatsManager.getTotalBytes(uuid)));
                    Log.d("AppLog", "getUsedBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, (storageStatsManager.getTotalBytes(uuid) - storageStatsManager.getFreeBytes(uuid))));
                    Log.d("AppLog", "getFreeBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStatsManager.getFreeBytes(uuid)));
                    Log.d("AppLog", "storage stats for app of package name:" + getPackageName() + " : ");

                    final StorageStats storageStats = storageStatsManager.queryStatsForPackage(uuid, getPackageName(), user);

                    Log.d("AppLog", "getAppBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStats.getAppBytes()) +
                                    " getCacheBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStats.getCacheBytes()) +
                                    " getDataBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStats.getDataBytes()));


                                    try {
                                        textView.setText("Storage : " + storageVolume.getDescription(context) + " : " + storageVolume.getState() +
                                                "\n\n" + "Total Bytes : " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStatsManager.getTotalBytes(uuid)) +
                                                "\n\n" + "Used Bytes : " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, (storageStatsManager.getTotalBytes(uuid) - storageStatsManager.getFreeBytes(uuid))) +
                                                "\n\n" + "Free Bytes : " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStatsManager.getFreeBytes(uuid)) +
                                                "\n\n" + "getAppBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStats.getAppBytes()) +
                                                "\n\n" + " getCacheBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStats.getCacheBytes()) +
                                                "\n\n" + " getDataBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStats.getDataBytes()) +
                                                "\n\n" + "storage stats for app of package name : " + getPackageName());


                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            });

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExternalStorageStats` as explained in the function below. By using this function you will get storage usage by getting image bytes, audio bytes, video bytes, app bytes. Here the function is but keeps in mind that its only works in API level 26 and above.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void getResults(){

    StorageStatsManager storageStatsManager = (StorageStatsManager)getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    ExternalStorageStats externalStorageStats = null;
    UserHandle user = android.os.Process.myUserHandle();
    try {
        externalStorageStats = storageStatsManager.queryExternalStatsForUser(StorageManager.UUID_DEFAULT,user);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long totalBytes = externalStorageStats.getTotalBytes();
    long imageBytes = externalStorageStats.getImageBytes();
    long audioBytes = externalStorageStats.getAudioBytes();
    long videoBytes = externalStorageStats.getVideoBytes();
    long appBytes = externalStorageStats.getAppBytes();

    String string= ("Total Bytes : " + getSize(totalBytes) +
                    "\n" + "Image Bytes : " + getSize(imageBytes) +
                    "\n" + "Audio Bytes : " + getSize(audioBytes) +
                    "\n" + "Video Bytes : " + getSize(videoBytes) +
                    "\n" + "App Bytes : " + getSize(appBytes));
}
```